# Rerending only freestyle on previous render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I'm playing with Freestyle in Cycles. I'm tweaking setting and rerendering. I'm spending a lot of computing time rerendering stuff expensive stuff, then doing a quick freestyle pass with new settings.

Is there a way to keep the "main" Cycles render, and only rerender the freestyle pass?

Comment: If what you want to change in freestyle can also be changed via the compositor, the following approach may also be useful to you: 
Since Blender 2.83 there is an option to set Freestyle as **a render pass** in "View Layer Properties". After you have activated this option, there is a dedicated "freestyle" layer in the compositor. 
This is also described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114309/render-background-and-freestyle-in-different-image-layers/202723#202723)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create two separate render layers and use one for the actual render, and the second one exclusively for the Freestyle strokes.
Combine them in the compositor and then update only the freestyle layer when you tweak settings.

Procedure described in detail here [Adjusting Freestyle in the Blender compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38725/adjusting-freestyle-in-the-blender-compositor)