# How to render only one render layer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, freestyle

How to render just one render layer?

[image: two render layers, how to render only one?]

[Rerending only freestyle on previous render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48712/rerending-only-freestyle-on-previous-render/48714#48714) and [Adjusting Freestyle in the Blender compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38725/adjusting-freestyle-in-the-blender-compositor) explain how to separate the rendering into "normal render" and freestyle-only. Unfortunately they do not explain how to render only one layer.

An code method is explained in [Re-render single layer without losing all the others (Blenderartist.org)](https://blenderartists.org/t/re-render-single-layer-without-losing-all-the-others/666855/3):

1. Open a **Python Console**
2. Run `bpy.ops.render.render(layer="FreeStyle")`

This appears to not be working:

1. It freezes Blender (no progress bar or view)
2. It takes as long as pressing the render button, so it seems to not work and just renders all layers.

I suspect there might be a non-code UI way to do it. Is there?

Answer (score 6):

In Blender 2.80 and later you can find settings for current layer in Layer Properties in Properties pane. Fourth tab from the top, and the relevant setting is at the top of the pane.

To switch layers use layer switcher at the very top right corner of the window.

[image: screen showing layer selection and layer properties]

Answer (score 1):

In the **Node Editor**:

1. Press the **Render Layers** node that handles the render layer, which you want to re-render.
2. Press the camera icon in the bottom right corner.

or:

1. Select the Render Layers node that handles the render layer, which you want to re-render.
2. Press **N**.
3. In the sidebar, in the **Properties** section, press the camera icon.

[image: Node Editor with relevant controls]