# How do I render only the particular view layer I want instead of always including a full composite pass?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a scene and I'd like to render out PNG layers to make life easier in post-production. I have set up all my layers to render separately. However, Blender is also spending time rendering out a composite of all layers even though I only have the following node setup:

[image]

Note that there is no composite setup, but I still get one. It's adding a lot of extra time to my render.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/155633/86891

Comment: In the nodes you are showing, you are saving the composite pass, not any other render pass (like diffuse, normals. or other). And if you are looking to "make your life easier" in post production **avoid png**, use OpenExr Multilayer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save all render passes to EXR image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image)

Comment: @Gorgious - If my read on that first link is correct, then I need to uncheck Render Single Layer, correct?

Comment: @Susu - To clarify, I am going to be in a 2d workflow (Premiere & After Effects). I have been operating under the assumption that PNG is a suitable format for that.

Comment: PNG is not a format to transport linear information (which is what you should use for compositing). Plus PNG is not capable of using associated alpha channel

Comment: The PNG format utilizes an alpha channel. That's the main reason I selected it. I will look into what EXR is and what benefits it confers.

Comment: Alpha on PNG is unassociated, so you won't be able to have pixels that are luminous and transparent at the same time (like fire or reflections on glass). For proper compositing you want to keep the data as linear. EXR will have proper associated alpha, and saves the images as scene referred. Think of it as a way to save the render layers intact, with no distortions created by the color management.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I figured out the answer:

Under RENDER and VIEW LAYER, make sure that *Use for Render* is UNCHECKED. This will eliminate that particular layer. In the compositor, plug in the the layers that you want to export per my initial graphic. Or, select the checkbox for *Render Single Layer* (while making sure you are actually on that layer).