# Render background and freestyle in different image layers

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

Can anyone tell me how to render an image (tiff) with two different layers, one for background (need it white) and one for the rest of the render (just freestyle lines).
I am using Blender 2.8

Thanks,
Bhupen

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38725/adjusting-freestyle-in-the-blender-compositor and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48712/rerending-only-freestyle-on-previous-render

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I don't think any of those answers related. The OP is using 2.8 which has a different way of addressing the raised issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, Blender isn't capable of creating multilayered TIFFs.
However, you could use other software to acchieve that.

### 1. Change the file format for the output

In *Output Properties* you would specify the file format "TIFF".
Any file format that supports transparency (and can be converted by ImageMagick) should be fine.

[image: Shows the "TIFF" file type option in "output properties"]

### 2. Assign Freestyle its own render pass

Since Blender 2.83 there is an option to set Freestyle as a render pass in *View Layer Properties*.

[image: Shows the relevant "As Render Pass" option in "view layer properties"]

In the compositor, Freestyle can then be processed separately.

[image: Connect the freestyle render pass with the composite node.]

In case you have multiple layers that you like to export in a single run, you could use *File Output Nodes*.

For the default cube, the rendered image would look something like this.

[image: Shows freestyle lines with a transparent background]

### 3. Use other software to create a layered TIFF

Any software that is capable of creating multilayered TIFFs will work.

For [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) this command should work. (As ImageMagick doesn't have a graphical user interface, this is executed from the command line.)

```
convert canvas:white -resize 1920x1080! blender_render.tif -compose over multilayered_result.tif
```

- The resolution should match the resolution of your render.
- Without the trailing exclamation mark, the background would keep its ratio (a square).

Comment: I misunderstood the original question and therefore changed the answer so that it better fits it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to separate what you want into different collections.  Then above collections there are view layers.  Make view layers for what you want separated.  Go to the collections and right click to exclude from each view layer.  Now go to the compositing tab to work with nodes.  Add Render Layer nodes for each view layer and select the view layer in the box at the bottom of the Render Layer node.  It's also a good idea to make the view layers transparent.  To do this go to Properties>Render>Film and tick the Transparency check box.